# Autherization flow - one party accessing another party as third party - is this a correct way to do so?

Tags: authentication, oauth2

I've been suggested an authorization flow between three parties that seems not secure to me, and I would like to know if I'm assuming correctly.

Let's say Party A has many customers (one of them let's call it Customer X) with data in Party A.

Party A is allowing Customer X to get data from their API. In order to do that:

- Customer X downloads a client_id and client_secret
- Customer X uses client_id and client_secret to hit the /auth endpoint
- /auth endpoint returns a token.
- Customer X now uses the token in an authorization header (Authorization: Bearer YOUR_TOKEN_HERE) to hit API endpoints

Until this point this makes sense to me.

Now, let's say that we include Party B, which wants to access data in Party A in behalf of Customer X. What Party A is suggesting to do is:

- Customer X downloads a client_id and client_secret
- Customer X goes to Party B and stores client_id and client_secret there
- Party B uses client_id and client_secret from Customer X to hit the /auth endpoint
- /auth endpoint returns a token.
- Party B now uses the token in an authorization header (Authorization: Bearer YOUR_TOKEN_HERE) to hit API endpoints in behalf of Customer X

To me it seems weird that Party A will encourage Customer X to bring that client_id and client_secret to another party.

I want to know if this is a normal flow, and if it isn't, suggest what is the most common way for Party B to access Party A data in behalf of Customer X.

Comment: I'm no expert on this subject, but It sounds to me pretty much the same as the way OAuth2 is used by Google to grant 3rd-party access to their APIs - https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2  (Where Party B is effectively just a different application).   As far as I can tell, the most important thing would be that Party B is configured as a separate application on the OAuth2 service with its own `client_id` and `client_secret`.

Comment: Auth0 docs also seem to suggest that this is a common solution:  https://auth0.com/docs/applications/first-party-and-third-party-applications

Comment: Interesting. Thank you! It looked weird to me that you would be giving a username and password to a third party... Because in this case client_id and client_secret are not unique for each of these third party applications.

Comment: The third party should ideally not be prompting users for their username/password, instead it should be redirecting users to the OAuth2/OIDC provider login screen using their client_id.     Upon successful login, the OAuth2 provider should redirect the user back to the 3rd party with an authorisation code which the 3rd party can exchange for an access_token.     There's an excellent overview here; https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/10/21/illustrated-guide-to-oauth-and-oidc

Comment: As for multiple applications/3rd parties sharing the same client_id and client_secret, this sounds like something to be ideally avoided, especially if the client_id grants privileges that the 3rd party otherwise wouldn't need.

Comment: Exactly Ben, the flow you are describing is what I've used before, where Party B directs user to Party A, and after giving permissions, Party A sends token to Party B.